# How do I search an arraylist for a string in a new class?

Tags: java, class, search, arraylist

I'm working on an assignment for a Java class to write a program that makes an empty array of a new class person that contains a string for their name, then lets you add new people and search for them. The problem is that the search function I wrote always says that the searched names aren't in the array even if they should be.

```
import java.util.*;
public class ArrayOfPeople {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    boolean running = true;
    while (true){
    ArrayList<person> people = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("press 1 to add people");
    System.out.println("press 2 to search people");
    System.out.println("press 3 to exit program");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = scanner.nextInt();
    
        
    switch (input) {
        
        //add people
        case 1:
            System.out.println(" how many people would you like to add?");
            int quantityOfNames = (scanner.nextInt());
            for(int i=0; i<quantityOfNames; i++){
                System.out.println(" what is the new person's first name?");
                person newPerson = new person();
                newPerson.fName = scanner.next();
                people.add(newPerson);
            }
            break;
            
        //search people
        case 2:
            System.out.println("what is the persons first name?");
            String searchedName = scanner.next();
            person searchedPerson = new person();
            searchedPerson.fName = searchedName;
            
            boolean found = people.contains(searchedPerson);
            if (found){
                System.out.println(searchedName + " IS in the system");
            }else{
                System.out.println(searchedName + " is NOT in the system");
            }       
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried comparing the two strings with an if statement inside a for loop, but that only ever gave me successful search messages, then I tried the .contains method for Arraylist, and that's what's only giving me unsuccessful messages now. But I need it to tell me yes if the name is in the array and no if it isn't.

Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Also this is my first post here so please let me know if there's etiquette I'm missing or something.

Comment: You haven't provided your `person` class, which needs to override `equals` for `ArrayList.contains` (`people.contains`) to work.

Comment: Make sure you’re interpreting the assignment correctly. Your first sentence says to create an array, but the code uses an `ArrayList`, which is different than an array. The instructor might not want you to be using the collection API and the `contains` method if it hasn’t been taught in the course at this point. It might help if you include the exact assignment text in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was stated in the comments, override equals. Or just iterate over the list as shown. Remember that case matters when comparing strings.  There is also an `equalsIgnoreCase` method.

The following assumes that `name` is a String field of the `Person` class.

```
String searchedName = <some persons name>
boolean found = false;
for (Person p : people) {
   if (p.name.equals(searchedName)) {
        found = true;
        break;
   }
}
if (found){
     System.out.println(searchedName + " IS in the system");
}else{
     System.out.println(searchedName + " is NOT in the system");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One issue is your code recreates a new collection every pass through the loop:

```
while (true){
ArrayList<person> people = new ArrayList<>();
```

So assuming you first choose "1" to add people to the list, the next iteration `people` is reinitialized (empty) and then any search "2" would not find any results.

So just move the initialization outside the loop:

```
ArrayList<person> people = new ArrayList<>();
while (true){
```

You should also move the scanner creation outside as well - just need one instance for the program.